# Given a word and a text, we need to return the occurrences of anagrams

Tags: c++, algorithm

Given a word and a text, return the count of the occurrences of anagrams of the word in the text.
For eg. word is “for” and the text is “forxxorfxdofr”, anagrams of “for” will be “ofr”, “orf”,”fro”, etc. So the answer would be 3 for this particular example.

I have got the brute force approach which is getting all the permutations of the word, then compare if the text contains it, and increase the number of occurrences, but that is O(N^2) approach. I'm looking for a better complexity.

Comment: Did you write "wrod" intentionally in the title of your question?

Comment: It was fun, you should have left it :-)

Comment: In this text `forxxorfxdofr` x are separators?

Comment: @cpp no, x are not separators.

Comment: What is the expected result for `forf` ? 2 or 1.

Comment: @EdHeal This is not a homework, this was an interview problem by amazon that I found, and I wanted to get a better approach.

Comment: @Jarod42  a nice drill. I would assume that is two anagrams.

Comment: how many anagrams of "for" would "forfg" contain?

Comment: @groovy  for, and orf. They are two.

Comment: For the complexity, there are several things... size of the alphabet, length of the anagram, length of the text, and potentially the result number. Your solution is O(#anagram ! #text).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can simply look for the character count.

Say for example that you're looking for anagramms of `look`. So, you're looking for:

- a 4 charachter length word,
- with 1 l, 2 o and 1 k.

Simply process the first 4 letters, store the counts. Check whether you have a match.
Add the next character (increment), remove the old character (decrement). Check again.
And so on...

Comment: +1 for giving a clear and concise idea without handing over a complete homework solution.

Comment: @us2012 This is not a homework solution, it was an interview problem at Amazon, and I was just thinking about it to get a better solution.

Comment: @Karoly storing the count of each character would be in a hashtable for example ? otherwise it would be still O(N^2)

Comment: If you can assume ASCII char set and 8-bit `char`s etc, you can 'cheat' and have a length 256 vector/array for occurrences. Otherwise, yeah, a hashmap `std::unordered_map` or similar sounds good.

Comment: your serch length is 3 in that case. So you will reach `for`, then you'll reach `orf`. And I don't really care how you store it, as long as the access is O(1), the overall algorithm is O(N) ;)

Comment: How do you check if anagram match ? The naive way is O(#alphabet), so a final solution of O(#alphabet #text) which may result in something worse than O(#anagram! #text).

Comment: @Jarod42: alphabet is typically small (eg: ascii), so no problem there. If it's large, it's enough to check the letters from the search word. You can also maintain a total count for matching characters of the alphabet of the search word to do quick elimination (for my example #l + #o + #k must be 4).

Answer (score 3):

[TooTone's O(*n*) solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18811680/411022) suffers from having to compare two 256-element vectors for each character of the input text.  This can be avoided by tracking the number of positions at which the two vectors differ, and registering a match when this number goes to zero.  In fact, we don't even need to store two different vectors at all, since we can just store one vector containing their difference.

Here's my version implementing these optimizations.  It's written in plain old C, but should work under C++ with appropriate adjustments:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h> /* for UCHAR_MAX (usually 255) */

int find_anagrams (char *word, char *text) {
    int len = 0;           /* length of search word */
    int bin[UCHAR_MAX+1];  /* excess count of each char in last len chars of text */
    int mismatch = 0;      /* count of nonzero values in bins[] */
    int found = 0;         /* number of anagrams found */
    int i;                 /* generic loop counter */

    /* initialize bins */
    for (i = 0; i <= UCHAR_MAX; i++) bin[i] = 0;
    for (i = 0; word[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        unsigned char c = (unsigned char) word[i];
        if (bin[c] == 0) mismatch++;
        bin[c]--;
        len++;  /* who needs strlen()? */
    }

    /* iterate through text */
    for (i = 0; text[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        /* add next char in text to bins, keep track of mismatch count */
        unsigned char c = (unsigned char) text[i];
        if (bin[c] == 0) mismatch++;
        if (bin[c] == -1) mismatch--;
        bin[c]++;

        /* remove len-th previous char from bins, keep track of mismatch count */
        if (i >= len) {
            unsigned char d = (unsigned char) text[i - len];
            if (bin[d] == 0) mismatch++;
            if (bin[d] == 1) mismatch--;
            bin[d]--;
        }

        /* if mismatch count is zero, we've found an anagram */
        if (mismatch == 0) {
            found++;
#ifdef DEBUG
            /* optional: print each anagram found */
            printf("Anagram found at position %d: \"", i-len+1);
            fwrite(text+i-len+1, 1, len, stdout);
            printf("\"\n");
#endif
        }
    }
    return found;
}


int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc == 3) {
        int n = find_anagrams(argv[1], argv[2]);
        printf("Found %d anagrams of \"%s\" in \"%s\".\n", n, argv[1], argv[2]);
        return 0;
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <word> <text>\n", (argc ? argv[0] : "countanagrams"));
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: nice one. In production code, I would have shrunk the `vector`s down to 26 long or maybe even used `map`s, but the idea of avoiding a comparison altogether by using a count of mismatched letters is really sweet!

Answer (score 2):

Essentially you can slide a window of the length of your word over your input and keep a count of how many of each letter are in the window. When the letter counts in your sliding window match the letter counts of your word, you have a match.

Let your word length be `n`, and your current position be `curr`. Create an array, or `vector`, `windCounts` of length 26. The entry `windCounts[i]` stores the number of occurrences of the i<sup>th</sup> letter of the alphabet seen from position `curr - n - 1` to `curr`.

What you do is you advance `curr`, and keep your array `windCounts` up to date, by decrementing the letter that has dropped out of the back of the sliding window, and incrementing the letter count that has appeared in the front of the sliding window. (Obviously until `curr` > `n`, you only increment, you just build up your sliding window to the length of your word.)

In C++, you can use a `vector` for the counts of letters in your word, and for the counts of letters in your sliding window and simply use `vector::operator==` to do the equality.

*Edit*: the algorithm is `O(N)`, where `N` is the length of the text to search. This can be seen from the code below where the loop body is executed for each letter that you slide the window.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm> // for_each 

using std::string;
using std::vector;

#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    const string text = "forxxorfxdofr";
    const string word = "for"; 

    // Counts of letters in word
    vector<int> wordCounts(256); // optimization: cut down from 256 to 26 
    std::for_each(word.begin(), word.end(), 
        [&] (char c) { wordCounts[c]++; } );

    // Current position of end of sliding window
    string::const_iterator curr = text.begin() + word.size();
    // Initial sliding window counts
    vector<int> windCounts(256);
    std::for_each(text.begin(), curr,
        [&] (char c) { windCounts[c]++; } );

    // Run sliding window over text
    int numMatches = 0;
    while (1) {
        numMatches += wordCounts == windCounts;
        if (curr == text.end()) {
            break;
        }
        windCounts[*(curr - word.size())]--;
        windCounts[*curr]++;
        ++curr;
    }

    std::cout << numMatches << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Complexity: `O(#alphabet #text)`. (#alphabet can be see as a constant).

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks. As you say the size of the alphabet is a constant. You're right that I didn't update the counts correctly. There were several bugs :( I only tested the original code on the original problem. I've done a bit more testing and will do a little bit more later on today. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I have taken two string namely str and occ. Str is the original strin and occ is the sting for which we have to find out the count. Using strncpy function I have copied the length of occ i.e. n chars into a temp array and then checked whether it is a permutation of the occ string or not.

```
#include<iostream.h>  
#include<conio.h>  
#include<string.h>

int permutate(char str1[],char str2[]);  
int permutate(char str1[],char str2[]) {  
    int c[256]={0},i,j;  
    for(i=0;i<strlen(str1);i++)  
        c[str1[i]]++;      

    for(i=0;i<strlen(str2);i++) {  
        c[str2[i]]--;      
        if(c[str2[i]]<0)   
            return 1;   //not a permutation       
    }  
    return 0;           //permutation   
}  

int main()  {
    //enter code here  
    char str[]="forxxorfxdofr",occ[]="for",temp[10];
    int n,i,x,t=0;   
    n=strlen(occ);
    for(i=0;i<strlen(str);i++) {
        strncpy(temp,str+i,n);    //copy the n char from str to temp
        x=permutate(temp,occ);
        if(x==0)                  //if string is a permutation
            t++;
    }
    cout<<"Count = " << t;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
o(n) solution in Python
```

def check(s1,s2):

```
function takes in s1 as the text and s2 as the text to be checked from here for


c=0
n=len(s2)
ck=sorted(s2)
mk=''.join(ck)


 this loop will pick from s till the length of s2 that is 'for'



for i,item in enumerate(s1):
    if s1[i] in mk:
        p=s1[i:i+n]
        jk=sorted(p)
        er=''.join(jk)

now just comparing the both sorted strings if they are equal then they were anagram 

        if er == mk:
            c+=1
return c
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution in C++.

It replaces generating all permutations with sorting both the word and a section of the string.

```cpp
        cin >> sstring;
        cin >> word;

        ocurrences = 0;

        sort(word.begin(), word.end());

        for (int i = 0; i < sstring.size(); i++)
        {
            string copy = sstring.substr(i, word.size());

            sort(copy.begin(), copy.end());

            if (word == copy)
            {
                ocurrences++;
            }
        }

        cout << ocurrences << endl;
```