# Given a word and a text, we need to return the occurrences of anagrams.. Is my approach correct?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, pseudocode

Basically Im trying to work out a solution to the problem [Given a word and a text, we need to return the occurrences of anagrams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18811511/given-a-word-and-a-text-we-need-to-return-the-occurrences-of-anagrams) . However, I wasnt able to quite understand some of the solutions posted there. So, I tried to convert the problem into the problem of finding permutations of a given text.  Here's my algorithm (pseudocode), Id like some insight to see if its right and also some insight into finding its complexity.

```
int findAnagramOccurencesinText(String input,String find)

//generate a list of all possible permutations of the letters in find and store in a list
// eg/ if find ="dog"  then list =["god","odg","dog","gdo","ogd","dgo"]

int occurances=0;
for String (perm:list)
{
     index=-1;
     while(index<input.length)
      {
          index=input.indexOf(perm,index);
          if(index!=-1)
             occurances++;
          index+=1;

      }
}
return occurances;
}
```

Also is the complexity O(#inputlength)? Any insight on how to find the complexity of this particular algorithm(if its correct) would be appreciated.

**EDIT : I understand this is a O(n!) solution. Is there any modification I can make to it, to make it more efficient?** (Other than scrapping the entire approach and moving to the O(n) approach mentioned in the linked question)

Comment: Isn't it just O(inputlength*listlength), because the permutation list length also varies?

Answer (score 0):

There are `O(n!)` permutations of a set of `n` elements.

So, assuming the string searching algorithm is linear time, the time complexity would be:

```
O((findLength)! inputLength)
```

The above assumes the `find` is without duplicates, if it isn't, the formula is [slightly more complicated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#In_combinatorics).

Comment: Could you take a look at the edit? Any thoughts would be really helpful.

Comment: No, I don't see any modification that would significantly improve your current solution - I suggest you move to one of the approaches mentioned in the linked question.